# Best python module to generate a simple PNG graph based on a CSV

Tags: python, csv, graph

Whats in your opinion the best module to generate a bar graph in png format based on the .CSV below? I am looking for something really sikmple because the idea is to attach it to an email that is also also sent by python. I am not interested in web/html visualisation, just a picture format. If you could also point me to some tutorials 'd be great!

Using python 3.4.

The .csv contains the data below(example):

```
Month, Price
Jan, 15
Feb, 17
Mar, 8
Apr, 34
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You could do it like in this example https://plot.ly/pandas/bar-charts/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I dont need a web graph, only to generate a .PNG in my machine to be used later. Can pandas do that?

Comment: You can do it with plot

ax = df.plot()
fig = ax.get_figure()
fig.savefig('asdf.png')

Comment: do you know where could I find some tutorial to understand the code that in in that website? And also how could load the .csv into it. thanks a lot.